# Better approach to converting two JSON structures

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{ 
  "Foo": [{"total": 2000, year: 1}, {"total": 3400, year: 2}, {"total": 5000, year: 3}],
  "Bar": [{"total": 1000, year: 1}, {"total": 2400, year: 2}, {"total": 7000, year: 3}],
}
```

I need it in the form:

```
[
  { "Foo": 2000, "Bar": 1000, year: 1},
  { "Foo": 3400, "Bar": 2400, year: 2},
  { "Foo": 5000, "Bar": 7000, year: 3}
]
```

The best we can come up with is a quite frankly embarassing:

```
var yearMap = {};

// Initialising the map of years eg. {1: { } , 2: {} .. }
for (var key in data) {
    var foos = data[key];
    $(foos).each(function(index, val) {
        yearMap[val.year] = { };
    });
}

// Iterates through the data and just puts the commission total against the year
for (var key in data) {
    var foos = data[key];
    $(foos).each(function(index, val) {
        yearMap[val.year][key] = val.total.value;
    });
}
```

Can anyone come up with a cleaner approach?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no problem to be solved. It might be better off on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's wrong with your solution in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it cleaner(basically it's doing the same ), but it iterates only 1 time over the entire data:

```
var yearMap = {};

$.each(data,function(k,v){
  $.each(v,function(kk,vv){
    if(!yearMap[vv.year])yearMap[vv.year]={};
    yearMap[vv.year][k]=vv.total
  });
});
```